# Is it just me or Stackexchange is mainly composed of StackOverflow and Aviation?

Tags: discussion

This one is simple
Whenever I hear stackexchange, only StackOverflow and Aviation comes to my mind, is it just me or Stackexchange and Aviation makes 70 Percent of the whole domain ?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @JonathanIrons not my downvote, but the tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: I've been using the site for like 4 years now, and I don't think I've ever even been on Aviation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you think of when you hear "Stack Exchange" is highly dependent on *why* you use it or what industry you're in.

While I'm aware of Stack Overflow and Aviation, I don't use them much (or ever, in the case of the latter). It's difficult to *not* think about Stack Overflow when you hear "Stack Exchange" as that's the original site.

However, I'm a daily user of the [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) site, the [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) site and a moderator on [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) and [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), so when I hear Stack Exchange, those are the sites I think of first.

If you want to see some numbers on this, feel free to check out the top sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). You can see that, while Stack Overflow is the lead on most everything, the other top sites for questions per day, traffic, total users and total questions change for the other metrics. I like to check out these lists from time to time to see what sites are really drawing eyeballs and getting a lot of content and which aren't.